# OSX sdk Filesystem monitor copy progress?

Tags: cocoa, filesystems, osx-yosemite

I have been looking around, but the literature seems pretty dense, is there a way to monitor a directory/filesystem and take a look at what file is being copied and how long it will take to complete?

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005289-CH4-SW4

I have found this but I am not sure if it will be sufficient for my needs.